# Is there a point setting a priority for intent filters on unordered broadcasts?

Tags: android, android-intent

The docs only mention "The order applies only to synchronous messages; it's ignored for asynchronous messages." 
Does this mean that the priority is only looked at by Android for 'ordered broadcast?'

```
  <receiver android:name=".receivers.PhoneStateReceiver" >
        <!-- TODO it's supposed to be an un-ordered broadcast -->
        <intent-filter android:priority="99999999999" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

... making the above 'priority' useless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this mean that the priority is only looked at by Android for 'ordered broadcast?'

Yes.

> ... making the above 'priority' useless?

I have no idea if `PHONE_STATE` is sent ordered or not.

Comment: isOrdered() in the receiver told me PHONE_STATE indeed was un-ordered. Cheers.